# User notification are restricted to a limit in iOS app how to send unlimited for alarm app?

Tags: ios, swift, usernotifications, unusernotification

I am working on an [alarm app project(Click for GitHub link)](https://github.com/varun-naharia/Alarm) this code is working fine but the problem is notifications are limited to approximately 64 at the time so I am unable to send continues notification until the user responds to the notification. I read some the apple restricts local notification to only 64 but I have seen many apps on apple store those are sending notification continuously here few links from the apple store.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/red-clock-free-edition-the-minimal-alarm-clock/id567374573?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarmy-alarm-clock/id1163786766?mt=8

Anyone help to understand how this app is able to send continuously and I tried these apps are sending notification until the user responds to the app (for more than 1 hr I checked). Below is the code for setting single notification.

```
    let comingSunday =  findNext("Sunday", afterDate: fireDate.adding(minutes: item))
    let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([ .year, .month, .weekday, .hour, .minute, .second], from: comingSunday!)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: alarm.repeatAlarm)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "\(alarm.uuid)0\(item)", content: notificationContent, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
                         if let error = error {
                           print("Unable to add notification request, \(error.localizedDescription)")
                         }
    }
```

**[Video of Alarmy app with continuous notification](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kh9uyrge293szdn/VID_20180405_170344.mp4?dl=0)**

**Please install and run app from App Store and notice how notification are working in above apps before posting answer**

Comment: I don't know is it correct way or not but I think you can delete local notifications from app and reschedule it once it reached on max limit...

Comment: but to delete and reschedule notification the app has to be in running mode, All these alarm app in app store are removed from background and there internet is disabled but they managed to send notification unlimited time

Comment: @VarunNaharia did you get the solution? if you get the solution can you update the answer. I want to achieve same.

Comment: No I didn't find the solution

Comment: did u find any workaround @VarunNaharia

Answer (score 4):

You could store information about all your notifications in the local database.

For example, if you have more than 64 notifications, you can post 64 notifications via UNUserNotificationCenter, and others save to the local database.

If one of local notification completed (already presented), you could get information about the first notification from the local database and schedule it (also you can remove it from the local database, or add specify key (isScheduled for example)).

You can handle this operation in the delegate method:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void)
```

Answer (score 0):

may be trivial, but if You simply need to be notificated more times, 
I usually use:

UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(
    timeInterval: 60.0,
    **repeats**: true)

SO you can add ONE that counts for one, and it can coexists with your other (real) notification.
Once user has tapped, You can kill it.

Comment: Have you seen the video of alarmy app ?

Answer (score 0):

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void)
```

The Delegate only works when the app is running